# ngModel binding data angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a response json data like this:

```
{
  "trainingClassId": 22,
  "classId": "class001",
  "startDate": 1541178000000,
  "endDate": 1510333200000,
  "examDate": 1510333200000,
  "numOfAttendee": "15"
}
```

on service:

```
getDetailApp(id: number):  Promise<any[]> {
    const url = `${this.URL}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

on ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.getAppDetail();
    };

     async getAppDetail(){
       await this.appService.getDetailApp(this.data.id).then(data =>this.sub = data);

      console.log("=="+this.sub.classId);
    }
```

in html file:

```
 <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="sub.classId" name="classId" id="classId" placeholder="Class ID">

            </mat-form-field>
```

when init html page, the input classID show data well. but in console browser it shows error message:

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'classId' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
```

after that, the page is crash. I cannot do anything on this.
Please advice me.

Comment: ...what is `this.sub` *before* the request completes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: i just add my service. The link which you suggest has difference issue with me. I have issue with updateDirectives

Comment: No, it's not different. `sub` is undefined, because you don't have the data right away.

Comment: because the console.log can show data: ==class001, and it show well on UI. but I guess I have a problem with  [(ngModel)], but i dont know why

Comment: Do [(ngModel)]="sub?.classId"

Comment: @Chau Tran: try to do it, i have a error message the error in console is displayed:Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression

Comment: Why do you have a Pipe error when you're not using any pipe? That's weird. Anyway, try [ngModel]="sub?.classId" (ngModelChange)="someMethod($event)"

Comment: @ChauTran: yup, tks anh. I have to separate it to 2 [ngModel] and (ngModel), and it works